# Simplifying an Array containing an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of customer licenses I am sorting through and creating a live search function with an array that updates properly. The issue I am facing is that I want my filtered array to be an array like this `[[{},{},{},{},{}]]` currently after typing in a word to filter the array looks like this instead `[ [{}], [{},{}], [{},{}] ]` or something similar whereas its an array with multiple arrays instead of just one.

I'm sure its something simple that I have overlooked in the past couple of hours trying to figure out how to achieve what I want.

```js
function FilterResults(term, results)
{
    return results.reduce((filtered, group) => 
    {
        const match = group.filter(({ customerName }) => customerName.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()));
            
        match.length && filtered.push(match);
        
        return filtered;
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you really want an array inside of another array but
You can do it like this one.
I have spread and then pushed the `match` array and returned the result in a new array.

```
  function FilterResults(term, results)
{
    const res = results.reduce((filtered, group) => 
    {
        const match = group.filter(({ customerName }) => customerName.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()));
            
    match.length && filtered.push(...match);
    
    return filtered;
}, []);

return [res]
}
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you. I knew it was going to be something stupid simple I over looked... I tried probably 12 different things other than just doing that... Thank you again!